# Error connecting to EFS mount from AWS ECS fargate container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I'm trying to setup via CloudFormation an EFS mount for self-hosted Prometheus. Below is the CloudFormation for my setup:

```
Resources:
  ServiceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: 'Prometheus SG'
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${NetworkStackName}-VPCID'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        # Allow access from the Load Balancer only
        - SourceSecurityGroupId:
            Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${LBStackName}-SG-LB'
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 9090
          ToPort: 9090
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub 'SG-Prometheus-LB-${Stage}'

  EFSSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: 'Prometheus EFS SG'
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${NetworkStackName}-VPCID'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        # Allow access from the ECS Service only
        - SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ServiceSecurityGroup
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 2049
          ToPort: 2049
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub 'SG-Prometheus-EFS-${Stage}'

  MountTarget1:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${DataStackName}-EFSID'
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref EFSSecurityGroup
      SubnetId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${NetworkStackName}-PRIVATE-SUBNET-A1'

  MountTarget2:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${DataStackName}-EFSID'
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref EFSSecurityGroup
      SubnetId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${NetworkStackName}-PRIVATE-SUBNET-B1'

  Prometheus:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: ListenerRule
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      DesiredCount: !FindInMap [ ECSTaskDefinition, !Ref Stage, DesiredTaskCount ]
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 200
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: 'Prometheus-Container'
          ContainerPort: 9090
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref ServiceSecurityGroup
          Subnets:
            - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${NetworkStackName}-PRIVATE-SUBNET-A1'
            - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${NetworkStackName}-PRIVATE-SUBNET-B1'
      EnableECSManagedTags: true

  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: Prometheus
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      Cpu: !FindInMap [ ECSTaskDefinition, !Ref Stage, CPU ]
      Memory: !FindInMap [ ECSTaskDefinition, !Ref Stage, Memory ]
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: 'Prometheus-Container'
          Essential: true
          Image: !Sub '${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${RepositoryName}:${ImageTag}'
          Cpu: !FindInMap [ ECSTaskDefinition, !Ref Stage, CPU ]
          Memory: !FindInMap [ ECSTaskDefinition, !Ref Stage, Memory ]
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 9090
          MountPoints:
            - SourceVolume: 'Prometheus-Volume'
              ContainerPath: '/prometheus'
              ReadOnly: false
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group:
                Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${DataStackName}-CW-LogsGroup'
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
              awslogs-stream-prefix: 'PrometheusApp'
      Volumes:
        - Name: 'Prometheus-Volume'
          EFSVolumeConfiguration:
            FilesystemId:
              Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${DataStackName}-EFSID'
            RootDirectory: "/"
            TransitEncryption: ENABLED
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      TaskRoleArn:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${LBStackName}-TaskRoleArn'
      ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt ExecutionRole.Arn

  TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${NetworkStackName}-VPCID'
      TargetType: ip
      Port: 9090
      Protocol: HTTP
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: '200'
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: 'deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds'
          Value: '60'
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckPath: /status
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 2
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2

  ListenerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      ListenerArn:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${LBStackName}-LB-LISTENER'
      Priority: 2
      Conditions:
        - Field: path-pattern
          Values:
            - /*
      Actions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
          Type: forward

  TaskPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: 'Prometheus-TaskPolicy'
      Roles:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${LBStackName}-TaskRole'
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: EnablePutMetricData
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
            Action:
              - cloudwatch:PutMetricData

  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'

  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Sub "Prometheus-${Stage}"
```

Everything gets deployed successfully but the containers die with the error message: `ResourceInitializationError: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: Failed to resolve "fs-xxxxxxxxxxx.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. I've checked https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/fargate-unable-to-mount-efs/ and don't think we have an issue with zones.
Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Does your VPC have DNS enabled? How about including your ECS task definition in your question so we can see how you are configuring the EFS mount. Are you using EFS access points? Are the VPC subnets you are deploying the ECS task in public or private? If public are you enabling public IPs on the ECS tasks? If private, do they have a route to a NAT Gateway?

Comment: - VPC does not have DNS disabled
- Task definition is already included
- Not sure about access points
- Private subnets
- Should they have a route to a NAT gateway? I'd have thought communicating with an AWS service would not require that?

Comment: Yes private subnets would need a route to a NAT Gateway, or VPC endpoint, unless you've enabled EFS Access Points in the subnet already. Your assumption that communicating with an AWS service would not require that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the POSIX user of your access point is not configured.

From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-access-points.html):

> If you do not specify the [POSIX] ownership and permissions for an access point root directory, Amazon EFS will not create the root directory. All attempts to mount the access point will fail.

If it isn't POSIX, a different layer of AWS security is blocking your connection (security groups, subnet acls, or iam permissions).